# Swift Task extension: Success == Sendable, Failure == Error necessary?

Tags: swift, task, generic-constraints

Seeing in the Apple doc that the `Task` is defined as:

```swift
@frozen struct Task<Success, Failure> where Success : Sendable, Failure : Error
```

I've seen a number of code online where people add extensions to `Task` with constraint like:

```swift
extension Task where Failure == Error {}
```

and/or

```swift
extension Task where Success == Sendable {}
```

For example, the code [here](https://github.com/ChimeHQ/ConcurrencyPlus/blob/main/Sources/ConcurrencyPlus/Task%2BRelay.swift) extends `Task` with the constraint `Failure == Error`. Given that `Task` is defined with constraint `Failure: Error` I wonder what's the specific need for adding `Failure == Error`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A type satisfies the `: Error` constraint if it conforms to `Error`. For example, this type:

```
enum MyError: Error {
    case somethingBadHappened
}
```

However, `MyError` does not satisfy an `== Error` constraint, because the only type that satisfies this constraint is `Error` itself. It says "equal to" `Error`, after all :)

You can apply the same logic to `Sendable`.

The versions of [`Task.init`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/init(priority:operation:)-5k89c) and [`Task.detached`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/detached(priority:operation:)-8a4p6) that take a throwing closure, and `relayResult` in your linked code, all requires `== Error`, because they all create tasks from a throwing closure.

You don't know what specific type of `Error` a throwing closure is going to throw. The best you know is it throws `Error`. Therefore, these methods can only create a task whose failure type is exactly `Error`. They cannot create a task whose failure type is, say, `MyError`,

```
// let's say that calling Task.init with Failure being MyError is allowed
Task<SomeSuccessType, MyError> {
    // some code that throws AnotherError
}
```

because the throwing closure can throw `AnotherError`.

But let's say the "throwing other types of errors" problem is magically handled somehow, this `== Error` also serves as an easy way for the compiler to infer the `Failure` type when you call these methods. You don't need to write the type of error the task can throw explicitly, like I did above.

I can't think of when you would use *exactly* `Sendable` as the `Success` type off the top of my head though. That doesn't seem very useful.

`Sendable` doesn't have any syntactic requirements, so it is functionally the same as using exactly `Void` (aka `()`, and also conforms to `Sendable`) as the `Success` type, to indicate "this task just "finishes" and has no result". If I were to choose, I would definitely choose `Void` instead of `Sendable` to express this idea.